# UITableViewCells disappear after didSelectRowAtIndexPath perform?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, tableview, didselectrowatindexpath

I have two tableviews, in the first `UITableView` (contact table view) all cells loaded and when I touch a cell it will go to detail contact and every thing is fine.
In the second `UITableView` (detail contact) when I touch cell (call contact) and  second `UITableView` method `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` perform, it works but causes all data (contacts) in first `UITableView` to disappear. How can I fix that?

---

P.S.:

(If I disable `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` in second `UITableView`, data remains in first table view)
(there is not segue between table view)

---

First `UITableView`:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    static NSString *kCellId = @"UIContactCell";

    UIContactCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:kCellId];
    //cell.imageLabel.alpha=0;
    cell.imageView.image=nil;
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[[UIContactCell alloc] initWithIdentifier:kCellId] autorelease];
        cell.imageView.image=nil;

        // Background View
        //        UACellBackgroundView *selectedBackgroundView = [[[UACellBackgroundView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero] autorelease];
        //        cell.selectedBackgroundView = selectedBackgroundView;
        //        [selectedBackgroundView setBackgroundColor:LINPHONE_TABLE_CELL_BACKGROUND_COLOR];
    }
    OrderedDictionary *subDic = addressBookMap[[addressBookMap keyAtIndex: indexPath.section]];

    NSString *key = subDic.allKeys[indexPath.row];
    ABRecordRef contact = subDic[key];
    CFDataRef imageData = ABPersonCopyImageData(contact);
    UIImage *image = nil;

    image = [UIImage imageWithData:(NSData *)imageData];


    // Cached avatar
    id data = avatarMap[@(ABRecordGetRecordID(contact))];
    if(data == nil) {
        //CFRelease(imageData);
        //image = [FastAddressBook getContactImage:contact thumbnail:true];
        if(image != nil) {
            avatarMap[@(ABRecordGetRecordID(contact))] = image;
        } else {
            avatarMap[@(ABRecordGetRecordID(contact))] = [NSNull null];
        }
    }
    else if(data != [NSNull null]) {
        image = data;
    }
    NSString *name=(NSString *)ABRecordCopyValue(contact, kABPersonFirstNameProperty);
    NSString *family=(NSString *)ABRecordCopyValue(contact, kABPersonLastNameProperty);

    if(image == nil) {
        //image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"avatar_unknown_small.png"];
        RandomColor *random=[[RandomColor alloc] init];
        cell.avatarImage.backgroundColor=[random makeColor:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@",name,family]];

        cell.imageView.image=nil;
        // cell.imageView.backgroundColor=[UIColor whiteColor];

        cell.imageLabel.alpha=1;

    }
    //        CFDataRef imageData1 = ABPersonCopyImageData(contact);
    //        UIImage *image1 = nil;
    //
    //        image1 = [UIImage imageWithData:(NSData *)imageData1];

    else{
        cell.imageLabel.alpha=0;}
    cell.imageView.image=nil;
    cell.avatarImage.image = image;


    cell.contact = contact;
    cell.imageView.image=nil;
    return cell;
}


- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"DialerStoryboard" bundle:nil];
    ContactProfileViewController *nextview = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"Profile"];
    OrderedDictionary *subDic = addressBookMap[[addressBookMap keyAtIndex: indexPath.section]];
    ABRecordRef lPerson = subDic[[subDic keyAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
    // ContactProfileViewController *nextview=[[ContactProfileViewController alloc] init];
    nextview.person=lPerson;
    [self presentViewController:nextview animated:YES completion:^{

    }];
}
```

Second `UITableView`:

```
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    AddContactTableViewCell *cell=[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"mesal" forIndexPath:indexPath];
    CFStringRef phoneNumberRef = ABMultiValueCopyValueAtIndex(self.phoneNumbers, indexPath.row);
    CFStringRef locLabel = ABMultiValueCopyLabelAtIndex(self.phoneNumbers, indexPath.row);

    NSString *phoneNumber = (NSString *)phoneNumberRef;
    CFRelease(phoneNumberRef);
    CFRelease(locLabel);
    cell.numberLabel.text=phoneNumber;
    cell.boarderButton.layer.borderColor=cell.boarderButton.titleLabel.textColor.CGColor;
    //[cell setSelectionStyle:UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone];
    return cell;
}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

     [tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];
     NSString *dest=NULL;;
     CFStringRef valueRef = ABMultiValueCopyValueAtIndex(self.phoneNumbers, indexPath.row);
     if(valueRef != NULL) {
         dest = [ContactProfileViewController localizeLabel:(NSString*) valueRef];
         CFRelease(valueRef);
     }
    if(dest != nil) {
        NSLog(@"touch2 cell baby");
        NSString *displayName = [FastAddressBook getContactDisplayName:person];
        DialerViewController *controller = DYNAMIC_CAST([[PhoneMainView instance] changeCurrentView:[DialerViewController compositeViewDescription]], DialerViewController);
        if(controller != nil) {
            [controller call:dest displayName:displayName];
        }
    }
}
```

UIViewController Methods for SecondTableview(ContactProfileviewcontroller):

```
-(void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated{

}

-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{

        [super viewDidDisappear:animated];
    //    [_tableView reloadData];
}



- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.phoneNumbers = ABRecordCopyValue((__bridge ABRecordRef)(self.person), kABPersonPhoneProperty);

  }

- (void)viewDidDisappear:(BOOL)animated {
   [super viewDidDisappear:animated];
}
```

In FirstTableviewController:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    [self changeView:History_All];

    // Set selected+over background: IB lack !
    [linphoneButton setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"buttonR"]
                 forState:(UIControlStateHighlighted | UIControlStateSelected)];

    [linphoneButton setTitle:[[NSBundle mainBundle] objectForInfoDictionaryKey:@"CFBundleDisplayName"]
                    forState:UIControlStateNormal];

    [LinphoneUtils buttonFixStates:linphoneButton];

    // Set selected+over background: IB lack !
    [allButton setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"buttonch2"]
                    forState:(UIControlStateHighlighted | UIControlStateSelected)];

    [LinphoneUtils buttonFixStates:allButton];

    (tableController.tableView).backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor]; // Can't do it in Xib: issue with ios4
    [tableController.tableView setBackgroundView:nil]; // Can't do it in Xib: issue with ios4
}
```

//  ——--------------------

```
- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];
    if(![FastAddressBook isAuthorized]) {
        UIAlertView* error = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:NSLocalizedString(@"Address book",nil)
                                                        message:NSLocalizedString(@"You must authorize the application to have access to address book.\n"
                                                                                  "Toggle the application in Settings > Privacy > Contacts",nil)
                                                       delegate:nil
                                              cancelButtonTitle:NSLocalizedString(@"Continue",nil)
                                              otherButtonTitles:nil];
        [error show];
        [error release];
    //me
    //    [[PhoneMainView instance] changeCurrentView:[DialerViewController compositeViewDescription]];

       // [self presentViewController:error animated:YES completion:nil];
       [PhoneMainView.instance popCurrentView];


    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Where is your array is initializing,is it in viewdidload or viewwillappear in firstTableView,Can u add code of view didload  of firstview

Comment: Check your data source array for first tableview.

Answer (score 0):

This is happening because you have same data source tied up to both tableviews. What you can do is in your cellforRow and didSelect. Check which tableview you are using and perform action accordingly.